# How can i force visitors in woocommerce to login before they can access my shop?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

The below code does not work. It works only for the cart and the checkout for some reason. My guess is that is_shop returns false. I tried to hook it to template_redirect but again is not working properly. Help?

```
function woo_login_redirect() {
if (
! is_user_logged_in()
&& (is_woocommerce() || is_shop() || is_cart() || is_checkout())
) {
wp_redirect( '/ο-λογαριασμός-μου/' );
exit;
}
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'woo_login_redirect');
```

Comment: Try removing this line `&& (is_woocommerce() || is_shop() || is_cart() || is_checkout())` completely so the test is only whether or not the user is logged in.

Answer (score 1):

```
function woo_login_redirect() {
    if (! is_user_logged_in() && is_page('your page id')) {

        wp_redirect( '/ο-λογαριασμός-μου/' );

        exit;
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'woo_login_redirect');
```

Please visit this [**link**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/)

Comment: This will redirect all not logged in users to login page no matter where they are. You should add is_page() to your if statement as well.